# How can I get one particular value out of this table?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

So I have this table: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sp8q.png)

How do I obtain the cod_Armazem where it doesn't have any of the stocks at 0?

I am using SELECT cod_Armazem FROM table WHERE stock>0;

Comment: What do you mean by one particular value? You query should return 3 results based on the table you shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.cod_Armazem
FROM   table t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT *
       FROM   table
       WHERE  stock = 0
          AND cod_Armazem = t1.cod_Armazem);
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight JPortillo, but the result is only A2 since A3 has a 0 in one of the stocks and therefore becomes invalid, the query you wrote will print out this: 
A2
A3
A2

Comment: Okay, so you want unique values?, i.e. the sum of Stock for A2 and A3?

Comment: Basically I want to isolate A2 and the only restriction I have is that: If at least one of the stocks value is 0 then the respective cod_armazem has to disapear from the table.

Comment: That one worked like a charm! Thanks!
If it's not too much of a bother mind walking me through?
 So by using a subquery that references the main query we can go through the main table as many times as the entries right?

Comment: Something like that. Only the rows that meet the WHERE clause will be included in the results. The condition in the WHERE clause uses a subquery to check if other records in that same table with the same cod_Armazem and stock = 0 exist. The EXISTS is modified by the NOT that precedes it, so it is checking if there aren't any other records on the table for that cod_Armazem with stock = 0. DISTINCT modifies the SELECT so that it does not show duplicate rows. Otherwise it would show A2 twice, once for stock = 23, and again for stock = 10.

Comment: Got it! Thanks JPortillo, you rock!